# Why does nothing happen when I click on a link built with routerLink and queryParams?

Tags: angular

I have a few navigation links in an Angular 4.0.0 SPA that vary only by the query string on them. I'm building them like this:

```
  <!-- MONTH -->
  <li class="right">
    <a [routerLink]="[]" [class.active]="insights.interval===2" queryParamsHandling="merge" [queryParams]="{range: 'MONTH'}">
      <span>M<strong>MONTH</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <!-- WEEK -->
  <li class="right">
    <a [routerLink]="[]" [class.active]="insights.interval===1" queryParamsHandling="merge" [queryParams]="{range: 'WEEK'}">
      <span>W<strong>WEEK</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

If I then hover over these links they look correct:

```
/insights/brand/5889cdfea7eb8f0e7c56bc9f?range=MONTH
/insights/brand/5889cdfea7eb8f0e7c56bc9f?range=WEEK
```

But when I click them, nothing happens. No breakpoint set in the component is reached.

How do I debug the router and figure out why nothing is happening?

Is it ok that I'm passing nothing in here?

```
[routerLink]="[]"
```

Here's the routing, in case it matters:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'insights',
        component: InsightsComponent,
        canActivate: [User],
        children: [
          {
            path: 'brand/:id',
            component: InsightsBrandComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'brand-item/:id',
            component: InsightsBrandItemComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'item/:id',
            component: InsightsItemComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'venue/:id',
            component: InsightsVenueComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class InsightsRoutingModule { }
```

[edit]

Here's the router debug:

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: I've not seen an empty routerLink array. Not sure it would know how to route without something there? I'm surprised that hovering is giving you the correct route, tho ... so maybe it would work? Could you put together a Plunker that demonstrates your issue that we could use to help resolve the issue?

Comment: In that regard ... this conversation about null/empty routes could be of interest: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6971. From a quick skim it sounds like they cause the route to route to itself. I assume that *is* what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I just want to come back to the same route but with the query string changed. My component has some code that inspects the query string and grabs new data from an API based on that. But that code is not running.

Comment: I would suggest to download source code and add it to the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can see what's happening with routing is to turn on route tracing. I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ], { enableTracing: true })
```